# How can I hide my section title if there is no data in custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, php, genesis-theme-framework

I wrote this function with a foreach and I'm not able to figure out how to hide the section title if there are no custom fields in $lista. Where should I place the section title?

```
function opening_hours_custom_fields() {

/*Define custom fields in this case with Genesis*/
$lista = genesis_get_custom_field('_happy_day', $post->ID);

/*Section title */
echo '<h3>Happy Day</h3>';
/* the rule to display items in foreach loop */
if( $lista )
 {     
foreach( $lista as $key => $value ){
    /* if value is nothing the display none */
    if( $value != '')
    {   

        echo "<li> $value </li>";
    }

}
echo '</div>';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first loop over `$lista` and generate a new array of data that only has non-empty values. Now you can check `$values` to ensure there is data and output your title:

```
function opening_hours_custom_fields() {
    global $post;

    if ( $lista = genesis_get_custom_field( '_happy_day', $post->ID ) ) {
        $values = array();
        foreach ( $lista as $value ) {
            if ( $value != '' )
                $values[] = $value;
        }

        if ( $values ) {
            echo '<h3>Happy Day</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ( $values as $value )
                echo "<li>$value</li>";
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the solution I used and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the loop only will be executed if there are any custom fields you could just move the title just before the foreach loop:

```
/* the rule to display items in foreach loop */
if( $lista )
{  
  /*Section title */
  echo '<h3>Happy Day</h3>';

  foreach( $lista as $key => $value ){
```